# The order of element in $\mathbb{Z} / 2^{2014}\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Find the smallest integer $n$ such that $2^{2014}|17^n-1$. i.e. Find the order of $17$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/ 2^{2014} \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$.

I think we have to use the lifting the exponent lemma: If $v_2(n)$ is the 2-adic valuation (i.e. $v_2(n)=m$ if $n=2^mq, (2,q)=1$), $4|x-y, 2\not|x,y$, then $v_2(x^n-y^n)=v_2(x-y)+v_2(n)$.

To this end, we have $v_2(17^n-1)=v_2(17-1)+v_2(n)=4+v_2(n)$. If we set $4+v_2(n)=2014$, then we have $v_2(n)=2010$ and hence $n=2^{2010}$. Hence we have $2^{2014}\Vert 17^{2^{2010}}-1$. But then I only get $o(17) \leq 2^{2010}$, how can I find the actual bound? Thanks for helping.

Comment: Can you explain how you get that bound?

Comment: According to Maple, the order is equal to $2^{2010}$.  Don't know any easy way to prove that though ;-)

Comment: @David,can you please explain why the OP's approach gives us a bound and not the exact value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is exactly correct, I do not understand the confusion.

We find that if $2^{2014} | 17^n -1$, then $v_2(17^n -1) \ge 2014$. But by LTE, we find that $v_2(17^n -1) = 4 + v_2(n)$. Plugging this in, 
$$ \begin{align}
4 + v_2(n)&\ge 2014 \\
\implies v_2(n)&\ge 2010\\
\implies n&\ge 2^{2010}
\end{align}$$
As desired.

Comment: I think we need to check if $n$ does satisfy our original condition.We have just proved that $2^{2010}$ divides n,right?

Comment: @rah4927 yes, but earlier you proved that 2^2010 works. Thus 2^2010 is the order