# order of a prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

if $p$ is a prime with $$2^A ~~||~~ p-1$$ for some $A\geq 2$, and if $B\in \mathbb{N}$, it seems to be the case that the multiplicative order of $p$ in $$\mathbb{Z}/2^{A+B}\mathbb{Z}$$ is $2^B$.  How to prove that?

Comment: The multiplicative order of $7$ or $11$ mod $8$ is $2$.

Comment: @lulu note A at least 2 condition

Comment: Ah, missed that.

Comment: It's true and moreover $p$ doesn't have to be prime. The key point is (for $A \ge 2$) that $2^{A} \| (x-1)$ implies that $2^{A+1} \| (x^2- 1)$. This is clear because $(x^2-1) = (x-1)(x+1)$, and $2 \| (x+1)$. Or you could write $x=1+2^{A}y$ and then

$$x^2 = 1 + 2^{A+1}y \bmod 2^{2A},$$

and $2^{2A}$ is divisible by $2^{A+2}$ for $A \ge 2$.

Comment: @user687721 perfect. thanks

Comment: see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1041901/242)